# How do i extract the satewise data of coronavirus cases in INDIA(name of sate, affected and dead) from this website(https://www.mohfw.gov.in/)

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, data-science

this is the code to extract the html data from the class where my data is located. but how do i extract the required data(**the state wise data**) as it is not given in order
[website](https://www.mohfw.gov.in/)

```
import requests
import cloudscraper
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import pandas as pd
import time
import datetime
scraper = cloudscraper.create_scraper()
html = scraper.get("https://www.mohfw.gov.in/").text
data = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
li=data.find_all(class_='table-responsive')
li
```

Comment: We have already published an api for it.  https://api.metamug.com/covid/v1.0/india You can use this. Also you can see this api in action here https://corona-india.metamug.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about you use pandas. It is organized and creates a df directly. Eg in your case:-

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
url = 'https://www.mohfw.gov.in/'
html = requests.get(url).content
df_list = pd.read_html(html)
df = df_list[-1]
print(df)
```

Comment: How do i organize the data as in the table to a .csv file

Comment: try df.to_csv(file_name, encoding='utf-8'). Also If you feel the issue is resolved, please accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark on the left hand side in my answer. And feel free to upvote the answer.

Comment: @PrakharJhudele There's no reason to use `requests` here as `pandas` `read_html` can make the request on your behalf.

Comment: agree with you @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη. Thanks for the suggestion. (Y)

Comment: Appreciate your response but the list is not in the order, if it is possible to extract the table as it is into a csv file, would be helpful

Answer (score 2):

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_html("https://www.mohfw.gov.in/")[-1]

df.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)
```

Output: [Check-Online](http://www.sharecsv.com/s/09b637c5b534c6f24310303a47688764/data.csv)

[image]

Comment: Thanks but i want the State-wise data of covid19 cases in INDIA

Comment: change `[2]` to be `[-1]`

Answer (score 1):

The data is wrapped in a tbody element. You can use the following scrapy code:

```
import scrapy
tables= response.xpath("(//tbody)[7]")
for data in tables:
    date = data.xpath("..//tr/td/text()")
    title_text = data.xpath("(//tbody)[7]/tr/td/a/text()")
    title_links = data.xpath("(//tbody)[7]/tr/td/a/@href")

    yield {
        'Date': date,
        'Title': title_text,
        'Links': title_links,
    }
```